# Wheel Vibration - Right front tire

Tags: wheels

I had my tires checked because the car would vibrate at about 65 miles per hour. The tech found belt shift and flat spotting on right front tire.

Does the tire have to be replaced or could I just have it balanced?

Answer (score 1):

If there is a flat spot on the tire you will most likely want to get it replaced, depending on how bad the flat spot is. Just minor wear and you'll be fine with a re-balance as it'll wear normally around the flat spot.